# How sort rows for specific columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big DataFrame with 10 columns. I want to sort all rows just for specific columns (two). For example, if this be my data frame

```
      A  B  C
   0  5  1  8
   1  8  2  2
   2  9  3  3
```

I want it to sort it just for A and B but for rows so the answer should be like :

```
  A  B  C
0 1  5  8
1 2  8  2
2 3  9  3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `sort`

```
s=df[['A','B']]
s.values.sort()
df.update(s)
df
   A  B  C
0  1  5  8
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `np.sort` on that specific subslice of columns and assign it back using `loc`:

```
# df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']] = np.sort(df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']], axis=1)   
df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']] = np.sort(df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']])                                                                 
df                                                                                                                     

   A  B  C
0  1  5  8
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  3
```